# How do I get the pid of a spawned process using pexpect?

Tags: python, pid, pexpect

I am using pexpect to spawn a *bash* shell and then using sendline to execute other processes within the bash shell.

Is there any way to get the pid of the spawned bash shell?
How can I get the pid of the process that I have started within bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [documentation of the spawn class](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html) you'll find that you can get the pid of the spawned process with the `pid` attribute, so

```
spawnedBash = pexpect.spawn('bash')
print(spawnedBash.pid)
```

should print your spawned process's pid

Answer (score 4):

Manuel's answer is actually incorrect. But it's not his fault, it's a fault of pexpect instead.

Invoking this python code

```
child=pexpect.spawn("gdb")
child.pid
```

gave me the pid value of `14470`. But when I controlled it via bash, I saw that gdb had the pid value of `14473`. This probably happens because pexpect invokes a wrapper and returns the pid of the wrapper instead of the real process.